# JSF2.0 NPE on RenderResponsePhase when session is expired (viewRoot is null)

Tags: jsf-2, nullpointerexception, viewexpiredexception

My application uses JSF 2.0.6 and RichFaces 4.1.0.
I implemented an ExceptionHandler which normally displays all exception in popup windows, and is working fine.

But something goes wrong when I disable partial state saving with this context param:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or this one:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
  <param-value>/index.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When the session is expired, any action I do in the application throws a NullPointerException :

> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:96)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:509)

I looked into RenderResponsePhase.java:96 and it corresponds to this:

```
    ViewDeclarationLanguage vdl =
          vh.getViewDeclarationLanguage(facesContext,
                                            facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId());
```

In fact, the viewRoot is null !

This never happens when the Partial state saving is enabled or if the session isn't expired.

I need to activate the full state saving option for some reasons but I don't know how to handle correctly errors when the session is expired. I suppose this to be a JSF bug, and I'd like to fix it on my web app.

Additional information:
Server: Tomcat 6.0.18

Comment: Mojarra 2.0.6 is over 1.5 years old already. Have you tried the current version? The bug might already have been fixed (although I don't recognize this one).

Comment: Yes I tried, and it works fine with the latest version (2.1.14), but it's a bit long and complicated to change libraries on my project...

Comment: Well.. This is not a problem we could solve, right?

Comment: Ok, it was just in case it was possible to fix it without updating libraries. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could sneak a copy of the Mojarra-specific class containing the fix into the webapp source folder. It would get precedence in classloading over the one in the JAR. But I would really prefer just replacing the JAR altogether with a newer version.